# Why does this attempt on using balancing groups in Regex fail?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, balancing-groups

For the string `"1-2-3-4"`, I wanted to create a regex, that would give me the following matches, i.e. each matching pair of digits separated by 1 or more dashes:

1. `"1-2"`
2. `"2-3"`
3. `"3-4"`

with each digit in its own capture group.

First attempt (c# flavour):

```cs
(?<first>\d)-+(?<second>\d)
```

This gives me:

1. `"1-2"`
2. `"3-4"`

Obviously, at the point of getting the first match, I have consumed the digit `"2"` and so the next char to match from is the dash after `"2"`.

Then I ended up reading up on my c#-/Regex-skills and stumbled upon Balancing Groups, enter my stubbornness. As I understood, this should do it (but it doesn't):

```cs
(?<entire>(?:(?<first-entire>\k<entire>)|(?<first>\d))-+(?<second>\d))
```

This yields the same result as my first attempt. I would expect the `<first-entire>` thing would rewind the captures to previous match (if any), making the `\k<entire>` part now match the entire previous match (which after 1 iteration would be `"1-2"`), or - if first iteration - fall back to the `<first>\d` pattern.

What have I misunderstood?

**Update**:
Probably should have explained exactly what I was aiming to do - but hinted by commenter, found the solution to my aim, which was to remove all dashes (1 or more) that might occur between digits. Solved with a simpler positive look-ahead like:

```cs
Regex _stripTheDashes = new Regex(@"(?<digit>\d)-+(?=\d)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var stripped = _stripTheDashes.Replace(s, m => m.Groups["digit"].Value);
```

Will leave this as-is, since it's been closed as a duplicate. And apparently I was wrong about using balancing groups :)

Comment: You do not need any balancing construct, use `(?=(?<first>\d+)-+(?<second>\d+))`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, I realized too that lookahead/-behind was the right way. But I'm still curious as to if I could do it by using Balancing Groups - mostly to see if I have understood the concept wrong.

Comment: Your regex does not contain a balancing construct anyway. It won't help you get overlapping matches. It is only meant to push/pop group values from the group stack (capture collection) and check if the group capture collection is empty or not to determine if there is a fail or success.